# D3.js:Tracking user interaction with svg in GA

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, google-analytics, data-visualization

I want to fire an event handler to Google Analytics (ga.js) when a svg circle-element created with D3 is clicked.

I've come up with this:

```
var circlesIndbyggere = d3.select("#ID").selectAll("svg").data(dataset);

circlesIndbyggere
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", 50)
    .attr("cy", 150)
    .attr("r", 20)
    .attr("fill", "rgba(35,50,80,0.5)")
    .attr("onClick", "ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'circle', 4);")
```

Now, when I monitor the console with Google Analytics Debugger-ChromeExtension it does not seem to fire an event?

When the GA-snippet is written in the tag, like this:

```
<a onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'arrow', 4);">
    <img src="/"/>
</a>
```

...it seems to work fine

Answer (score 4):

I think it's preferable to listen to clicks like so:

```
.attr...
.on('click', function(node) {
    ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'circle', 4);
});
```

Advantages:

1. It works :)
2. Better readability. JS code in a string looks bad.
3. You can debug it, unlike a string. Doesn't dirty the DOM

Comment: Does the event will count only once per page? In documentation [https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events] I read the event is fired only once, for subsequent event I should update a tracker.